# inverse String in c

Tags: c, string

i've done a function that inverse a String(array of character) given in parameter , but it's not working , any idea why ?

I'm getting something like this : æIGt(Kt$0@

thanks you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
inverse(char *s)
{
    int i, taille = strlen(s);
    char r[taille];
    for (i = 0 ; i < taille ; i++)
    {
        r[i] = s[taille - i - 1];
    }
    r[i] = '\0';    
    return r;
}

int
main()
{    
    char s[] = "kira";
    char *r = inverse(s);

    printf("%s",r);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what is not working. Is it segfaulting? Failing to compile? Giving incorrect result?

Comment: And please write code that has consistent style and is readable. And also, the success value from `main()` is `0`. Or more precisely, `EXIT_SUCCESS`. And finally, if you reverse the string, you should think!!! How many characters do you have to swap? And then you will see why it doesn't work.

Comment: You're returning the address of a local array, but the array is allocated on the stack and is no longer available when the function returns.  You need to do one of three things:  (1) Have `inverse` allocate the array on the heap by calling `malloc`,  (2) Have the caller pass a pointer to the desired result array, or  (3) Have `inverse` reverse the argument string in-place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That variable gets destroied when the function inverse returns, so accessing the pointer after the function exits will return invalid data.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: @AmarBessalah, either allocate memory on heap by ```char *r = malloc(taille + 1)```, or make ```r``` an output variable, or just copy r content back into ```s```

Comment: @gg.kaspersky can you please explain to me why when i don't allocate, it's not working ? thanks

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Do not forget to inform the OP about the need for `if (r == NULL) return NULL;`. And a later `free()` somewhere.

Comment: @AmarBessalah, ```char r[taille]``` declaration makes a buffer with taille characters on the stack (local variables have stack storage). The data allocated on the stack goes away when the function exits. To fix this you need to allocated data on the heap, by using malloc. Heap data persists through function calls, but you need to manually free it, by calling ```free(r)``` after you don't need ```r``` anymore.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

It's slightly hard to tell from you question, because you haven't given any outputs, but my best guess is that it's because your returning a pointer to an item on the stack, which will get over-written by the next call, in your case `printf`.  You need to pass `inverse` a place to put its answer. Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void inverse(char *s, char *r)
{
    int i,taille=strlen(s);


    for(i=0;i<taille;i++)
    {
        r[i]=s[taille-i-1];
    }
    r[i]='\0';
}



int main()
{

char s[] = "kira";
char r[sizeof(s)];

inverse(s, r);    

printf("%s",r);

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another standard approach to reversing a string uses pointers to work from both the beginning and end of the string swapping two characters with each iteration. It swaps the original string in place (make a copy if you need to preserve the original, or pass a second string and place the reversed string in there)

```
/** strrevstr - reverse string, swaps 2 chars per-iteration.
 *  Takes valid string and reverses, original is not preserved.
 *  If 's' is valid and non-empty, returns pointer to 's',
 *  returns NULL otherwise.
 */
char *strrevstr (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) {     /* validate string is not NULL and non-empty */
        printf ("strrevstr() error: invalid string\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *begin = s;    /* pointers to beginning and end, and tmp char */
    char *end = begin + strlen (s) - 1;
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin)  /* swap both beginning and end each iteration */
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return s;
}
```

As you can tell, there are a number of ways to approach the problem, with this and the other answers provided, you should be able to tailor a solution to meet your needs.

There are advantages and disadvantages to every approach. There is nothing wrong with dynamically allocating a new block of memory to hold the reversed string, it just adds an additional responsibility to (1) preserve a pointer to the starting address for the new block so (2) it can be freed when no longer needed. If you need to preserve the original string, passing a pointer to an character array of sufficient size to hold the reversed string is another option preserve the original.

Look over all the answers and let me know if you have any questions.